# Windows 10 Upgrade BSOD (SYSTEM_SCAN_AT_RAISED_IRQL_CAUGHT_IMPROPER_DRIVER_UNLOAD)

Tags: bsod, windows-10-upgrade

After the Windows 10 setup files have downloaded and its rebooted into the upgrade process we seem to be getting this weird problem.

After the files have copied across (so the first part of the upgrade process) when its doing the installation/configuration i get a BSOD with the following error :

```
SYSTEM_SCAN_AT_RAISED_IRQL_CAUGHT_IMPROPER_DRIVER_UNLOAD
```

and i cannot seem to figure out what the cause is.

Machine Specs:

- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
- CPU: Intel Core i7 4790K Haswell Refresh Processor 4.0 GHz
- RAM: 16GB PC3-10666 1333MHz DDR3 Memory (2 x 8GB sticks)
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT740
- MOBO: Asus B85M-G Basic Micro ATX Motherboard
- Hard Drive Setup: All our machines have 1 SSD boot drive and 2x1TB Mechanical drives in a raid 1 setup

We have 2 other machines built pretty much the same and both of them have upgraded no problem, any ideas?

Comment: You need to determine what drivers are being loaded and provide us a list so we can give you an idea what driver is causing your problem

Comment: How do i find that out?

Comment: You can use WinDbg to analysize the .dmp file, BlueScreenViewer to determine which files were loaded at the time, and Autoruns to control which drivers are loaded when Windows boots.

Comment: share the file **setupmem.dmp** from the folder **$WINDOWS.~BT\Source\Panther** so that we can analyze it

Comment: were you able to get the dmp?

Comment: This was the only dump files/error logs the windows 10 upgrade "spat out" http://www82.zippyshare.com/v/qYB3KSER/file.html

Comment: next time please notify me with @ myusername that you replied. I only saw your post today after checking my old comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your crash `SYSTEM_SCAN_AT_RAISED_IRQL_CAUGHT_IMPROPER_DRIVER_UNLOAD (d4)`is caused by the driver `spac.sys` which was unexpected unloaded.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SCAN_AT_RAISED_IRQL_CAUGHT_IMPROPER_DRIVER_UNLOAD (d4)
A driver unloaded without cancelling lookaside lists, DPCs, worker threads, etc.
The broken driver's name is displayed on the screen.
When possible, the guilty driver's name (Unicode string) is printed on
the bugcheck screen and saved in KiBugCheckDriver.
An attempt was made to access the driver at raised IRQL after it unloaded.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff801158f3e40, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff8001bed49ec, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.63.amd64fre.th2_release.160104-1513

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: fffff801158f3e40

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 1

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff8001bed49ec

FAULTING_IP: 
spac+103e40
fffff801`158f3e40 ??              ???

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: f9e

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xD4

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiPageFault
03 nt!KiProcessThreadWaitList
04 nt!KiRetireDpcList
05 nt!KiIdleLoop


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
spac+103e40
fffff801`158f3e40 ??              ???

SYMBOL_NAME:  spac+103e40

MODULE_NAME: spac

IMAGE_NAME:  spac.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  103e40

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xD4_UNLOADED_MODULE_spac!Unknown_Function

BUCKET_ID:  0xD4_UNLOADED_MODULE_spac!Unknown_Function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xD4_UNLOADED_MODULE_spac!Unknown_Function
```

This driver seams to be part of the Barracuda NextGen Firewall F-Series. So uninstall this tool and do the upgrade.

Comment: Removed the firewall and it installed without a hitch! thank you.

Comment: nice to hear this. Can you please tell me what was the correct product name and which version have you used? I've reported this crash to Microsoft and they need more information.

Comment: Barracuda Network Access Client 4.1 x64 was doing this exact thing for me  when upgrading from the Anniversary Update to Creator Update.